# Pointer to NSWindow Xib after loading it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xib

In my code below, CustomWindow is a subclass of NSWindow.

```
CustomWindow *window = [[CustomWindow alloc] init];
if (![NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"NibName" owner:window])
[window center]; // doesn't work
```

How do you get a pointer to control your XIB after you load it so you can do things such as centering the NSWindow (I mean the serialised one that resides inside the XIB)?

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be using an `NSWindowController` subclass. `NSWindowController` is specifically designed to do exactly what you want to achieve and solves several problems that you will run into if you load the nib directly using the methods of `NSBundle`. You generally should always use an `NSWindowController` subclass to manage windows.

Create a subclass of `NSWindowController`:

```
@interface MyWindowController : NSWindowController {}
@end

@implementation MyWindowController
- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindow"];
    if(self)
    {
        //initialize stuff
    }
    return self;
}
//this is a simple override of -showWindow: to ensure the window is always centered
-(IBAction)showWindow:(id)sender
{
    [super showWindow:sender];
    [[self window] center];
}
@end
```

In Interface Builder, set the class of **File's Owner** to be `MyWindowController` and connect the `window` outlet of **File's Owner** to the window object in your nib.

You can then display the window by doing this:

```
MyWindowController* controller = [[MyWindowController alloc] init];
[controller showWindow:self];
```

Comment: I was doing everything you said already, except for "connect the window outlet of File's Owner". Once I did that everything worked. Thanks a bunch! +1 and Tick.

Comment: Make sure to uncheck the `Restorable` property of the window in IB.

Comment: @KeithSmiley Which editor is the `Restorable` property, or does this no longer apply to Xcode 5.x?

Comment: I really dont like statements like this "specifically designed to do exactly what you want to achieve and solves several problems that you will run into if you load the nib directly using the methods of" without telling me what problems are there? I couldn't find anything and no link explaining in detail what window controller does and why  need it.

Comment: Among other things, it correctly handles memory management of the objects stored in the nib.

Answer (score 2):

> In my code below, CustomWindow is a subclass of NSWindow.
>
> ```
> CustomWindow *window = [[CustomWindow alloc] init];
> if (![NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"NibName" owner:window])
> [window center]; // doesn't work
> ```
>
> How do you get a pointer to control your XIB after you load it so you can do things such as centering the NSWindow inside the XIB?

“centering the NSWindow inside the XIB” makes no sense (you would center it *on the screen*), unless you mean centering the NSWindow object that is inside the xib, in which case, why are you creating another NSWindow (CustomWindow) object outside of the xib?

Remember that a nib (or xib) is an archive of objects. If you want to use a window that you have in your nib, you need to create an outlet to point to that window, set the class of the File's Owner to be the class where you've added the outlet, hook up the outlet in IB, and appoint the object with the outlet as the File's Owner by passing it to the `owner:` argument. That object, as the owner, will then be responsible for working with the window. It may be (usually is, in my code) the same object that loads the nib.

Also, `init` doesn't work on NSWindow; you must use `initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:` or `initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:screen:`. Using `init` would only be valid if you've implemented `init` yourself in CustomWindow, and used one of those two selectors for the `[super init…]` message.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to make your window the File's Owner.  Normally you would pass `self` or some controller object there.  Then if `self` or that controller object has a CustomWindow `IBOutlet`, it will get hooked up when you call `loadNibNamed:`.  Check out [this post](http://radio-weblogs.com/0100490/2002/03/28.html) for example code.

Comment: CustomWindow is the controller object. It contains IBOutlets that get hooked up when I run the application. The controls on the window all work. Just can't figure out how to centre it.

Answer (score 0):

A XIB is a container for objects, it's not equal to a window. You can't center a XIB, you can only center a window contained in a XIB.

Also, the objects in the XIB are created when you load it. You don't pass an object as owner that then stands in for one of the objects in the XIB, you instead use IBOutlets to get references to the new objects created when loading the XIB and then you can interact with them.

The File's Owner object is a special object in XIBs, as it's the only object that is not created and that you can specify by passing it to `loadNibNamed:owner:`. It's your gateway between the XIB-created objects and your application.

Usually, the owner object is some kind of controller class. Set the File's Owner's class in Interface Builder to your controller class, then define some IBOutlets in the class, they will show up in Interface Builder on the File's Owner and you can connect your objects in the XIB to them.

Finally, when you pass your controller object to `loadNibNamed:owner:`, Cocoa will connect your IBOutlets to the newly created objects and you can use them to interact with them, e.g. to center a window in your XIB.

Comment: You describe what I already have setup. There are no problems with IBOutlets and I'm not trying to get a pointer to a XIB. The XIB contains an NSWindow which I want a pointer to

Comment: That's what you use the "File's Owner" in IB for. It's a proxy for the object you pass into the loadNibNamed: method. See the other answer.

Comment: Yes that's what I though. Turns out the issue was that I didn't have the File's Owner window outlet connected to the XIB's window object.